# Query XSD for value?

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I was provided an XSD file to fill in a value in XML i am generating for submitting to a web service.

The XSD defines values for Enumerations that contain annotations and other info.  Best way to describe is to show some of the XSD.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" ?> 
  <xs:schema xmlns="http://MyCompany/Schemas" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk   /2003" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://MyCompany/Schemas" id="NAICSTypes" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:simpleType name="NAICSType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:int">
      <xs:enumeration value="111110">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:appinfo>2007 NAICS Title</xs:appinfo> 
          <xs:documentation xml:lang="en-us">Soybean Farming</xs:documentation> 
        </xs:annotation>
     </xs:enumeration>
     <xs:enumeration value="111120">
       <xs:annotation>
          <xs:appinfo>2007 NAICS Title</xs:appinfo> 
          <xs:documentation xml:lang="en-us">Oilseed (except Soybean) Farming</xs:documentation> 
       </xs:annotation>
     </xs:enumeration>
     <xs:enumeration value="111130">
       <xs:annotation>
          <xs:appinfo>2007 NAICS Title</xs:appinfo> 
          <xs:documentation xml:lang="en-us">Dry Pea and Bean Farming</xs:documentation> 
       </xs:annotation>
     </xs:enumeration>
     <xs:enumeration value="111140">
       <xs:annotation>
         <xs:appinfo>2007 NAICS Title</xs:appinfo> 
         <xs:documentation xml:lang="en-us">Wheat Farming</xs:documentation> 
      </xs:annotation>
     </xs:enumeration>
     <xs:enumeration value="111150">
      <xs:annotation>
         <xs:appinfo>2007 NAICS Title</xs:appinfo> 
         <xs:documentation xml:lang="en-us">Corn Farming</xs:documentation> 
      </xs:annotation>
     </xs:enumeration>
```

Essentially, what i need to do is provide a value, like 111150, and get back "Corn Farming" as a result in c#

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To just query the XML you can use [SelectNodes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4bektfx9.aspx) or SelectSingleNode.  You'll also need to specify a namespace manager to the query.

Something like this:

```
XmlNamespaceManager nsMgr = new XmlNamespaceManager();
nsMgr.AddNamespace("xs", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
string value =
    doc.SelectSingleNode("//xs:enumeration[@value='111150']//xs:documentation", nsMgr
    ).InnerText;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this link to be very helpful when I was using C# to read xml files.

[Generate classes from XML](http://sharpertutorials.com/using-xsd-tool-to-generate-classes-from-xml/)

You can use the xsd tool in Visual Studio to create classes that will read xml files of a particular schema.  It will make the model classes and you can easily parse the data you want into them.  Similarly, it will be very easy to read certain attributes and children when you create the objects from the xml file.

I should add that an xsd file is itself an xml file.  You can apply this same concept to reading an xsd.

Comment: I tried that a little earlier.  I got the error "Warning: cannot generate classes because no top-level elements with complex type
 were found."  Might be because of the "SimpleType" defintion at the top.  Thanks though.